# Android to Android Bluetooth Tether

Tags: tethering, bluetooth-tethering

My android does a pretty good job doing a bluetooth tether for my PC (in which PC shares my Android's internet), but I was wondering how to get another **Android** device to connect/tether to it (my first android device)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by pairing the devices and enabling data on the first device. Steps are listed below.

1. Enable bluetooth on both the devices. *(Obvious!)*
2. Then, pair them up by clicking “Search for devices” on one of the devices and clicking on the name of other device. You’ll be asked to verify a PIN number. It doesn’t matter what the PIN number is, as long as it’s the same PIN number on both devices.
3. Go to Settings, choose `More` then choose `Tethering & Portable Hotspot`. In there, you have tick `Bluetooth tethering`. If you don’t, the *tether will not work!*
   [image]
4. On the second device, go to `Setting`s, then click on the word `Bluetooth` *(not the toggle – the word)*. Finally, click on the name of your second device you paired earlier. To get it all working, choose `Internet Access`.

   [image]
5. Now you should be able to use the data connection of your first device.

Comment: I did try that. What version Android is this? On my devices (4.1 & ~2.x) it just shows "File Transfer" (step#4) (on either devices, doesn't matter which phone's connection I share to whom)

Comment: @laggingreflex This should be available the devices running at GB or above. Screenshots aee from a Galaxy Nexus phone.