# Bluetooth Tethering on Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, bluetooth-tethering

I have a galaxy s4 and a tethering data plan and I can tether via wifi (Settings| Connections tab| More Networks| Tethering and portable hotspot| Mobile hotspot). I don't see any options for bluetooth tethering. Do I need a special app for bluetooth tethering?

[image: Before turning Mobile Hotspot on] [image: After turning Mobile Hotspot on]
<sup>Before and after turning on Mobile Hotspot (click images for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth tethering is a native function supported by Android. You do not need third party apps.

---

#### To tether your internet via bluetooth on your Galaxy S4:

Go to home Settings ► Connections ► More networks ► Tethering and portable hotspot ► and check Bluetooth tethering.

[image: Bluetooth Tethering]

As explained in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49855/23379), you can tether two mobile devices easily by pairing the devices and enabling data on the first device.

Comment: I don't see the bluetooth tethering in the menu

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi Not even after the Zuul's edit? *See the screenshot.*

Comment: Nope. That page doesn't have Bluetooth tethering option.

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi can you give us a screen shot please?

Comment: I added screenshots.